# Sort List of object on the basis of object's properties priority

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am having a class Student with some properties like:

```
public class Student {
   private String firstName;
   private String middleName;
   private String lastName;

   .....
}
```

I also have a list of Students which I have to Sort on the basis of priority of some properties. For example, First priority is `firstName`, Second is `lastName` and last is `middleName`. I have been asked this question in an interview. Using comparable I have done it for a single property but how can we sort on the basis of different priority?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, use [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) to easily chain comparisons.

```
Collections.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.firstName)
                                 .thenComparing(s -> s.lastName)
                                 .thenComparing(s -> s.middleName));
```